# determine a pattern in the input data using Map Reduce

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a set of numbers in certain order. The order is important and need to be maintained. I need to find the max number of consecutive numbers which qualify a condition.

***Example*** :

Condition : Prime number

Input Data : 1,3,2,4,7,5,3,11,2,4,6,**3,7,3,5,1,3,7,5**,4

```
Answer : 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution requires that you know the position i of each element of the input. This is not necessarily easy, but assume it for now.

First, imagine mapping each value to its index i in the list, and then only keeping the values for which the original value n met your condition. Then it's just a matter of finding the longest consecutive sequence in the input.

First, for each value in the input, at position i, take the top several bits of i, maybe top 8, as the output key. This will cause nearby values to go to the same reducer out of 256. Output this as the key and i as the value *if* the original value meets the condition.

Within each reducer, simply iterate through the indices and record the longest continuous sequence you see. Emit it as (start,end).

Finally you would read all of these values from the reducers, and take care of the case where two sequences from two different reducers actually run together (one ends at n, the next starts at n+1). Collapse those, then just report the length of the longest one.

This is also pretty simple in Spark.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. The idea of using the top bits to move the nearest positive matching values to same reducer is elegant. I will keep it in my tool box to solve other problems.
I ended up solving differently and unfortunately I am not able to share it for proprietary reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Because the order is importan, you should focus on the problem toward find the long and consecutive range(s) that meet the condition.

What about something like this:

You can parallelize your Input data including 5 more fields to each element in the serie:

- 1st and 2nd additional fields describe the begin and end of a range in order to keep locality,
- 3rd additional field that will be populated during reduce phase, this will keeps if the condition is meet
- 4th additional field that keeps if neighbor on the left has been already reduced
- 5th additional field that keeps if neighbor on the rigth has been already reduced

So:

### MAP

Input Data :

```
1,3,2,4,7,5,3,11,2,4,6,3,7,3,5,1,3,7,5,4
```

Would become something like:

Input Data : `(1,1,1,,true,false),(3,2,2,,false,false),(2,3,3,,false,false),(4,4,4,,false,false),(7,5,5,,false,false),(5,6,6,,false,false),(3,7,7,,false,false),(11,8,8,,false,false),(2,9,9,,false,false),(4,10,10,,false,false),(6,11,11,,false,false),(3,12,12,,false,false),(7,13,13,,false,false),(3,14,14,,false,false),(5,15,15,,false,false),(1,16,16,,false,false),(3,17,17,,false,false),(7,18,18,,false,false),(5,19,19,,false,false),(4,20,20,,false,true)`

So, that way, you would be able to parallelize keeping references to the order and with a clear stop condition.

### REDUCE

For the reduction phase, you would have to validate 2 conditions, and just reduce those tuples of elemens which meet both conditions, other way, does not reduce, but  potentially update the 4th,5th,6th additional fields, and then keep iterating until meet the stop condition.

1) Elements to redure are consecutive (neighbors)
2) Elements meet a specific condition, for your case: both elements are prime numbers

If do: you reduce
other case: keep going on the reduce phase, until no consecutive tuples in the data are still by evaluate, in other words, while any one of the elements keeps a value of false in its 4th or 5th fields.

Cases in the reduce:

a) you receive elements `(3,12,12,,false,false)` and `(7,13,13,,false,false)` to be reduced:

- are consecutive (neighbors)? yes
- are prime numbers? yes

then, you would return:  `("3,17",12,13,true,false,false)`

b) you receive elements `(6,11,11,,false,false)` and `("3,17",12,13,true,false,false)` to be reduced:

- are consecutive? yes
- are both prime numbers? no

then, you would return: `("3,17",12,13,true,true,false)` and `(6,11,11,false,false,true)`

c) you receive elements `(1,1,1,,true,false)` and `(3,2,2,,false,false)` to be reduced:

- are consecutive? yes
- are both prime numbers? no

then, you would return `(1,1,1,false,true,*true*)` and `(3,2,2,false,*true*,false)`

d) you receive elements `(5,15,15,,false,false)` and `(3,17,17,,false,false)` to be reduced:

- are consecutive? no
- are both prime numbers? yes

then, you would return both as `(5,15,15,*true*,false,false)` and `(3,17,17,*true*,false,false)`

e) you receive elements  `(5,15,15,true,false,false)` and `(1,16,16,,false,false)` to be reduced:

- are consecutive? yes
- are both prime numbers? yes

then, you would return `("5,1",15,16,true,false,false)`

### OUTPUT

At the end you would get 8 elements:

- `("1,2,3",1,3,true,true,true)`

  - for: `(1,1,1,,true,false),(3,2,2,,false,false),(2,3,3,,false,false)`
- `(4,4,4,false,true,true)`

  - for: `(4,4,4,,false,false)`
- `("7,5,3,11",5,8,true,true,true)`

  - for: `(7,5,5,,false,false),(5,6,6,,false,false),(3,7,7,,false,false),(11,8,8,,false,false)`
- `(2,9,9,true,true,true)`

  - for: `(2,9,9,,false,false)`
- `(4,10,10,false,true,true)`

  - for: `(4,10,10,,false,false)`
- `(6,11,11,false,true,true)`

  - for: `(6,11,11,,false,false)`
- `("3,7,3,5,1,3,7,5",12,19,true,true,true)`

  - for: `(3,12,12,,false,false),(7,13,13,,false,false),(3,14,14,,false,false), (5,15,15,,false,false),(1,16,16,,false,false),(3,17,17,,false,false),(7,18,18,,false,false),(5,19,19,,false,false)`
- `(4,20,20,false,true,true)`

  - for: `(4,20,20,,false,true)`